# Secure Credentials in Angular Application hosted in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have an angular 6 application running on the Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) server. I am searching for he solution to secure the credentials (single sign-on secret key of siteminder etc) in server and access then in the application at run-time.

At run-time the application should access these credentials to perform the required authentication and authorization. Any code snippet or code that would help this access would be helpful.

Comment: You can pass credentials to your app in a couple ways, env variables are one and bound services are another. Bound services are easier to share if you're passing the creds/info to multiple apps, or if the service you want is from the marketplace. It doesn't have to be in the marketplace though, you can create a "user provided" service which is any data you want to share as a service. Env variables you would just access directly as an env variable in your app, bound services are part of `VCAP_SERVICES` which is an env variable that contains a JSON blob with all the service info.

Comment: That said, this all happens on the server side. You won't be able to access that information from your Angular app unless you expose it from the server to your app. Once you expose it to an app running in the browser, you should consider it's no longer secret. Any user of that app can view that information via browser dev tools. If you're using OAuth2, look at the implicit or Auth Code Flow w/PKCE which are made for in-browser apps. Hope that helps!